# Получить ключ массива циклом из другого массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть цикл:

```html
<? 
$array = $arResult["QUESTIONS"]["q17"]["STRUCTURE"];
$i = 1;
echo "<tr class='stroka-163'>";
foreach ($array as $key => $arAnswer){
  echo "<td><input type='text'  class='inputtext'  name='form_text_{$arAnswer['ID']}'/></td>"; 
  echo ($i%4==0?"</tr><tr style='display: none;' class='str stroka-{$arAnswer['ID']}'>":"");
  $i++;
}
echo "</tr>"; ?>
```

В итоге генерируется таблица со значениями такого типа (всего их 200 штук) :

```html
<input type="text" class="inputtext" value="" name="form_text_164">
<input type="text" class="inputtext" value="" name="form_text_165">
<input type="text" class="inputtext" value="" name="form_text_166">
<input type="text" class="inputtext" value="" name="form_text_167">
<input type="text" class="inputtext" value="" name="form_text_168">
```

В значение value="" я хочу вставить значения другого массива $arResult['arrVALUES']['form_text_164']. Можно ли как то подставить в цикл что бы по ID из первого массива генерировался ключ для второго???

Пробовал вот так, но я так понял это крайне не правильно:

```html
<? 
$array = array_merge($arResult["QUESTIONS"]["q18"]["STRUCTURE"], $arResult['arrVALUES']);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>";
$i = 1;
echo "<tr class='stroka-164'>";
foreach ($array as $key => $arAnswer){?>

<td><input type='text' class='inputtext' value='<?echo($arResult['arrVALUES']['form_text_{$arAnswer['ID']}'])?>'  name='form_text_<?echo($arAnswer['ID'])?>'/></td>

<?echo ($i%5==0?"</tr><tr style='display: none;' class='stroka-{$arAnswer['ID']}'>":"");
$i++; 
}
echo "</tr>"; ?>
```

Подскажите, возможно ли как ни будь сделать то что я пытаюсь? Может я просто не так это делаю или знаки какие ни те поставил или перепутал

Думал соединить массивы, но первый массив сложный, а во втором много чего лишнего находится и правильно соединить так как хотелось бы мне кажется не выйдет.

Comment: Попробуй вместо `foreach ` сделать цикл `for` и по индексу сможешь брать данные из обоих массивов.

Comment: `$arResult['arrVALUES'][$arAnswer['ID']]`?

Comment: @u_mulder так к сожалению не получится в итоге будет массив типа такого $arResult['arrVALUES'][164], а нужен именно вот такой $arResult['arrVALUES']['form_text_164'].  Попробую методом for сделать, как советовали выше.

Comment: Ну тогда `$arResult['arrVALUES']['form_text_' . $arAnswer['ID']]`, делов-то